# Search with images on Google Lens using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, webautomation

I wanted to search for a particular image via google lens programmatically. I wrote this puppeteer script to try some stuff out. But the main problem is that there is no `input[type=file]` tag used on the page so I am not getting how to upload an image without it via the puppeteer API

Here is the snippet

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: [] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com.my/imghp');
  console.log('Google Image Search page loaded');
  // await page.
  const button = await page.$('div.dRYYxd > div.nDcEnd');
  console.log(button);
  await button.click();
  console.log('Button clicked');
  await button.click();
  // console.log('Button clicked');

  const uploadButton = await page.$('span.DV7the');
  console.log(uploadButton);

      await uploadButton.click();
        console.log('Button clicked');
//   await uploadButton.uploadFile('./Cute-Cat.jpg');
})();
```